# Custom hibernate entity persister

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I am in the process of performance testing/optimizing a project that maps

```
a document <--> Java object tree <--> mysql database
```

The document, Java classes, database schema and logic for mapping is orchestrated with HyperJaxb3. The ORM piece of it is JPA provided by hibernate.

There are about 50 different entities and obviously lots of relationships between them. A major feature of the application is to load the documents and then reorganize the data into new documents; all the pieces of each incoming document eventually gets sent out in one outgoing document. While I would prefer to not be living in the relational world, the transactional semantics are a very good fit for this application - there is a lot of money and government regulation involved, so we need to make sure everything gets delivered exactly once.

Functionally, everything is going well and performance is decent (after a fair amount of tweaking). Each document is made up of a few thousand entities which end up creating a few thousand rows in the database. The documents vary in size, and insert performance is pretty much proportional to the number of rows that need to be inserted (no surprise there).

I see the potential for a significant optimization, and this is where my question lies.

Each document is mapped to a tree of entities. The "leaf" half of the tree contains lots of detailed information that is not used in the decisions for how to generate the outgoing documents. In other words, I don't need to be able to query/filter by the contents of many of the tables.

I would like to map the appropriate entity sub-trees to blobs, and thus save the overhead of inserting/updating/indexing the majority of the rows I am currently handling the usual way.

It seems that my best bet is to implement a custom EntityPersister and associate it with the appropriate entities. Is this the right way to go? The hibernate docs are not bad, but it is a fairly complex class that needs to be implemented and I am left with lots of questions after looking at the javadoc. Can you point me to a concrete, yet simple example that I can use as a starting point?

Any thoughts about another way to approach this optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run in to the same problem with storing large amounts of binary data.  The solution I found worked best is a denormalization of the Object model.  For example, I create a master record, and then I create a second object that holds the binary data.  On the master, use the `@OneToOne` mapping to the secondary object, but mark the association as lazy.  Now the data will only be loaded if you need it.

The one thing that might slow you down is the `outer join` that hibernate performs with all objects of this type.  To avoid it, you can mark the object as mandatory.  But if the database doesn't give you a huge performance hit, I suggest you leave it alone.  I found that Hibernate has a tendency to load the binary data immediately if I tried to get a regular join.

Finally, if you need to retrieve a lot of the binary data in a single SQL call, use the HQL `fetch join` command.  For example:  `from Article a fetch join a.data` where a.data is the one-to-one relationship to the binary holder.  The HQL compiler will see this as an instruction to get all the data in a single sql call.

HTH